Why doesn't Gordon Freeman help the survivors?
I'm just starting to watch a full HalfLife (One) gameplay on YT (I haven't ever played the game yet), and I noticed that Gordon Freeman never attempts to help the surviving scientist and security guards, and in one case even seems to cause a scientist's death by stepping on a shaky bridge. Why is this so?
Is it just the gamer that I'm watching that played like this, i.e. does the game make it possible for him to help them, or is it not possible?

Might be the gamer you are watching.
Watch this:




Saving Every Scientist in Half-Life

Also read this thread:
https://www.reddit.com/r/HalfLife/comments/d7gqsl/is_there_any_way_to_save_every_scientist_and/
Upshot is:

You cant save everyone,

but you can save a huge portion of them.

Most of the scientists that can't be saved have entirely scripted deaths where you can't do anything



although, even if you save them:

Even then, are you saving them?
They can't follow you to the emergency exit you are trying to get to (which you don't make it to) due to ladders/lifts/etc.

Details of certain saves or situations are in that thread, or in that video.
From my memory, it was nice if i could save them, but I wasn't entirely focused on trying to do so, more about just trying not to die myself.
The gamer might be on his umpteenth run through and just doesn't care about NPC's anymore and is just trying to complete the level.
